# Update/Refresh Bing's Traffic Overlay

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I am using Bing's Traffic map layer to display the traffic conditions over the Bing map.  Currently this only updates when the browser is refreshed. Would there be an easy way to update this live?  Maybe with a timer?  I can't find anything on setting up a timer in a constructor or an alternative to what I am currently doing.

TrafficTileSource.cs

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Core;
using System;

namespace MR.CommandBridge.VEMap.MapExtensions
{
    public class TrafficTileSource : TileSource
    {
        public TrafficTileSource()
            : base("http://t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/t{0}.png")
        {
        }

        public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
        {
            var quadKey = new QuadKey(x, y, zoomLevel);
            return new Uri(String.Format(this.UriFormat, quadKey.Key));
        }
     }
 }
```

This is the only code I had to add to create the Traffic layer on my map and I just use a toggle button elsewhere to turn it on and off.  But I would like it to update periodically when it is on.  Any help would be great.  I am just not sure the best way to go about doing this.  I am not asking for code rather just asking for the concept, but if you would like to provide code that would be great!

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-adding the layer?

Comment: I thought about doing that but I haven't been able to find any information on how to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to remove and add back your layer on a specific time interval and to add an extra parameter to avoid having a cache on client side.

In your case, your implementation could look like:

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Core;
using System;

namespace MR.CommandBridge.VEMap.MapExtensions
{
    public class TrafficTileSource : TileSource
    {
        public TrafficTileSource()
            : base("http://t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/t{0}.png?time={1}")
        {
        }

        public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
        {
            var quadKey = new QuadKey(x, y, zoomLevel);
            return new Uri(String.Format(this.UriFormat, quadKey.Key, DateTime.Now.Ticks));
        }
     }
 }
```

You can also use the modulo operator to use a cache for a certain amount of time or take profit of DateTime formats.

Also, one last tip would be to avoid using only `t0` in the url, you should add an extra parameter in your string format so you can switch between servers to load balance your usage.

Final code would look like this:

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl;
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.Core;
using System;

namespace MR.CommandBridge.VEMap.MapExtensions
{
    public class TrafficTileSource : TileSource
    {
        public TrafficTileSource()
            : base("http://ecn.t{0}.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/t{1}.png?time={2}")
        {
        }

        public override Uri GetUri(int x, int y, int zoomLevel)
        {
            var quadKey = new QuadKey(x, y, zoomLevel);
            return new Uri(
                String.Format(
                    this.UriFormat, 
                    quadKey.Key[quadKey.Key.Length - 1]
                    quadKey.Key, 
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("g", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)));
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Note: I did not check your tile url and I'm not describing the process to remove the layer. Let us know if you need help with this.